# How to find records which is unique by TypeOfCertifate and latest by CertificateStartDate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Original Records

[image]

I need highlighted records in output result

I have filtered this result by this SQL Query

```
select *
from tbl_Certificate
where StoreNumber = 's28433'
group by Id, StoreName, StoreNumber, TypeOfCertificate, CertificateStartDate, CertificateExpiryDate, Comments, VisibleToStore, AdminFilePath, StoreFilePath, NoExpiryDate, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate order by CertificateStartDate DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
;with
earliest_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by TypeOfCertificate
                                 order by CertificateStartDate) rn
    from tbl_Certificate
    where StoreNumber = 's28433')
select *
from earliest_cte
where rn=1
order by CertificateStartDate;
```